# Contribute to both a SEP IRA and solo Roth 401(k)?

Tags: united-states, ira, contribution, roth-401k

I am self employed in a business venture. Could I theoretically contribute to a SEP IRA where the maximum contribution is $50,000 and to a Solo Roth 401k where the max contribution is $17,500?

I couldn't find information on that combination, but this appears to have higher contribution limits than any other retirement tax deferred idea.

I like the idea of tax free growth and distribution in Roth plans, yet I really like the higher contribution maximum in the SEP plan where I could make a huge account much faster than with other kinds of IRAs – it would take ten years with a normal IRA to do one years worth of contribution – if that much funds were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the normal limits, A Solo 401(k) allows you to contribute up to 20% of net profits (sole proprietor) or 50% of salary (if a corporation), up to $49,000.

Note that the fees for 401(k) accounts are higher than with the IRA.
See [401(k)s for small business](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704039704574616230013475734.html).

Comment: I already contacted my broker about fees, there are no fees for me to have a solo roth 401k.

Comment: Am I crazy, or does this have _nothing_ to do with the question of contributing to both simultaneously? Edit: there's an actual answer [over here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/59195/can-i-contribute-to-a-sep-ira-and-a-solo-401k-for-the-same-business).