# Can I contribute to a SEP-IRA and a Solo 401(k) for the same business?

Tags: united-states, solo-401k, sep-ira

[This money.SE question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14034/contribute-to-both-a-sep-ira-and-solo-roth-401k) and [this BogleHeads forum thread](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=102421) both seem to ask about whether or not you can contribute to both a SEP-IRA and a Solo 401(k) at the same time for the same business. I'm not getting a clear answer anywhere.

If it matters, this is in regards to an LLC filing under Subchapter S. I'm hoping I can do a SEP-IRA now, and set up a Solo 401(k) if I hit the SEP-IRA limit. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contribute to both but the total contribution is capped:

> **More than one plan.** If you contribute to a defined
>   contribution plan (defined in chapter 4),
>   annual additions to an account are limited to the
>   lesser of $53,000 or 100% of the participant's
>   compensation. When you figure this limit, you
>   must add your contributions to all defined contribution
>   plans maintained by you. Because a
>   SEP is considered a defined contribution plan
>   for this limit, your contributions to a SEP must
>   be added to your contributions to other defined
>   contribution plans you maintain.

Source: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p560.pdf on page 6.